# Get the each row size of a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to get each row size of a table in MySQL i.e total size of the space taken by a row. Assume a table has BLOB column. Not all row will be of same size. I want to list out all BLOB column i.e text column which is of greater size. Similarly collective size of a single row.

Is it possible to retrieve each row size of a table in a single query?

Comment: What do you mean by "row size"? The actually used filesystem storage? The number of columns? The length of all strings appended?

Comment: if It is no of characters, then concat all column and have length function on final result, this will return size of each row.

Comment: @Khatir what you mean by row size can you explain more??

Comment: Voted to close the question since it's unclear what's being asked here.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30644836/341117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how to get the each row size of a table..However able to find the query for table, database sizes. It seems it is not possible.

List Table Sizes From a Single Database

Assume the database name as "example"

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
  ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (MB)`
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = "example"
ORDER BY
  (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)
DESC;
```

Entire databases size

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024
"Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ;

SELECT sum(ROUND(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024),2)) "Size in MB"
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_db_name";

SELECT table_schema as 'Database Name', 
        sum( data_length + index_length ) as 'Size in Bytes',       
        round((sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 4) as 'Size in MB'
 FROM     information_schema.TABLES
 GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Comment: Good and simple stuff. Thanks!