# MySQL - universal way of getting approx. row size in bytes

Tags: mysql

OK, I won't be mad if nobody wants to help me with this nonsense, but I wanted to have a way to get the approximate row by row byte size of a table in a MySQL console (well I'm using phpMyAdmins SQL window).

The inner query reads the desired table columns from the schema and group_concats them to a to a statement, while adding the char_length() function to every column name. I did not find a better way, than using SEPARATOR for this, but as the separator comes first after the first element, I add two nonsense elements : "empty" at the beginning and "zzempty" at the end. Thoses are stripped of with replace later.

The best part is, I think this code does what I want, but the problem is, the results get fetched but are not displayed.

**What is the easiest way to get the results fetched by the prepared statement?** Is the only way to get the results to put them into a table?

```
SET    @query = CONCAT('SELECT ',
 (select
   REPLACE(group_concat( column_name 
 ORDER BY
   CASE 
      WHEN column_name="empty" THEN 0 
      WHEN column_name = 'zzempty'THEN 99 
      ELSE 1 
   END,
   column_name   separator '`) + char_length(`'),
   'empty`) + ',
   '')     
 FROM
   (SELECT
      'empty' as column_name,
      '1' as id 
   UNION
   select
      column_name,
      1 as id     
   from
      information_schema.columns     
   where
      table_schema = 'DB_NAME'        
      and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' 
   UNION
   SELECT
      'zzempty' as column_name,
      '1' as id ) t1      
group by
   id),' FROM `TABLE_NAME`');   
SET
@query2 = REPLACE( @query, '+ char_length(`zzempty',  '')  ;  
PREPARE stmt FROM @query2;  
Execute stmt ;
```

In fact, I think there must be much easier way to get the row size, but I did not find any.

Comment: AndyZ did any of the answers here helped answering your question?

Answer (score 10):

It's easier to ask `MySQL` about it, using the [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html) statement:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name='ApiRequest'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: ApiRequest
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 105
 Avg_row_length: 1872
    Data_length: 196608
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 16384
      Data_free: 2520776704
 Auto_increment: 114
    Create_time: 2015-05-29 13:00:13
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_unicode_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `Table status` has a small bug in `Avg_row_length`! It doesn't count the avg of varchar fields that are null

Comment: Finally a workaround that worked :) Copied the table to a temporary one and deleted all rows but the one I was interested in. Then your solution gave me the exact row size.

Comment: NGL s3c, that's a pretty slick work around, I like it.  Just copy and trim to the row, then measure it and you got your length.